# Laplace derivative formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

This is a question from a sample test. I'm just not quite sure how my professor has gotten to this answer. I'm good up until the part where she starts differentiating

$\mathcal{L}${x$^2$y''}

= $\frac{d^2}{ds^2}$[s$^2$$\mathcal{L}${y} - sy(0) - y'(0)]

= $\frac{d}{ds}$[2s$\mathcal{L}$ + s$^2$$\frac{d\mathcal{L}{(y)}}{ds}$ - y(0)]

=2$\mathcal{L}${y} + 4s$\frac{d\mathcal{L}(y)}{ds}$ + s$^2$$\frac{d^2\mathcal{L}{(y)}}{ds^2}$

Comment: A step was skipped that might help you: $\mathcal{L}(x^2 y'')=\frac{d^2}{ds^2} \mathcal{L}(y'')$. After that they do the usual thing for the Laplace transform of a derivative, and then they are just taking the derivatives of the result.

Answer (score 1):

She applied the product rule:
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
So that:
$$\dfrac {d}{ds}(s^2 \mathcal{ L}(y))=2s \mathcal{ L}(y)+s^2\dfrac {d}{ds} (\mathcal{ L}(y))$$
Because $\mathcal{ L}(y)$ is also a function of $s$.